# Deal with 'new' keyword in PHP unit test

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, doctrine, phpunit

In my case I have a class such as:

```
class Logger
{
/**
 * @var EntityManager
 */
protected $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

/**
 * @param Model $model
 */
public function log(Model $model)
{
    $logEntity = new LogEntity();
    $logEntity->setOrder($model->getOrder());
    $logEntity->setType($model->getType());
    $logEntity->setScore($model->getScore());
    $logEntity->setCreated(new DateTime());
    $logEntity->setModified(new DateTime());

    $this->entityManager->persist($logEntity);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $logEntity;

}
```

Logger class is not testable because in my code 'new' keyword exists, in other hand Logger class and EntityManager class registered **singleton** in container and can't inject model as dependency.

How to change class for change to testable class?

LoggerModel is a Doctrine entity and use in Laravel framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem with a sample solution: **Factory Pattern**.

I need assertion, so when get a new model from factory assert it as mock.

And how?

I create a class with a method that can be a singleton service:

```
class LogFactory
{
    public function makeLogEntity()
    {
        return new LogEntity();
    }
}
```

In another service, inject factory class:

```
class Logger
{
/**
 * @var EntityManager
 */
protected $entityManager;

/**
 * @var LogFactory
 */
protected $logFactory;

public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, LogFactory $logFactory)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->logFactory = $logFactory
}

/**
 * @param Model $model
 */
public function log(Model $model)
{
    $logEntity = $this->logFactory->makeLogEntity();
    $logEntity->setOrder($model->getOrder());
    $logEntity->setType($model->getType());
    $logEntity->setScore($model->getScore());
    $logEntity->setCreated(new DateTime());
    $logEntity->setModified(new DateTime());

    $this->entityManager->persist($logEntity);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $logEntity;

}
```

Now I have a service that is mock able and call `$mock->willReturn()` function in test.